# Localization error: Undefined index: title

Tags: localization

I have a website with 4 locales enabled (en, jp, zh, th). For some reasons I can not access some entries (channel) for the Chinese (zh) locale. The page is well displayed in the front end but I can not edit the entry in the back end, I get this error:

`Internal Server Error
Undefined index: title`

Looking at the DB, the entries are there and they all have a title set in Chinese.
Do you have any idea what the problem is?
Thanks

**EDIT**
Below, the stack trace:

```
PHP notice

Undefined index: title

/Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/models/EntryVersionModel.php(39)

27     {
28         if ($attributes instanceof \CModel)
29         {
30             $attributes = $attributes->getAttributes();
31         }
32 
33         // Merge the version and entry data
34         $entryData = $attributes['data'];
35         $fieldContent = isset($entryData['fields']) ? $entryData['fields'] : null;
36         $attributes['versionId'] = $attributes['id'];
37         $attributes['id'] = $attributes['entryId'];
38         $attributes['revisionNotes'] = $attributes['notes'];
39         $title = $entryData['title'];
40         unset($attributes['data'], $entryData['fields'], $attributes['entryId'], $attributes['notes'], $entryData['title']);
41 
42         $attributes = array_merge($attributes, $entryData);
43 
44         // Initialize the version
45         $version = parent::populateModel($attributes);
46         $version->getContent()->title = $title;
47 
48         if ($fieldContent)
49         {
50             $version->setContentFromRevision($fieldContent);
51         }
Stack Trace
#0  
–  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(687): CApplication->handleError(8, "Undefined index: title", "/Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/models/EntryVers...", 39)
682         if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7', '>=') && $code === 2 && strpos($message, 'should be compatible with') !== false)
683         {
684             return;
685         }
686 
687         parent::handleError($code, $message, $file, $line);
688     }
689 
690     // Private Methods
691     // =========================================================================
692 
#1  
–  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/models/EntryVersionModel.php(39): Craft\WebApp->handleError(8, "Undefined index: title", "/Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/models/EntryVers...", 39, ...)
34         $entryData = $attributes['data'];
35         $fieldContent = isset($entryData['fields']) ? $entryData['fields'] : null;
36         $attributes['versionId'] = $attributes['id'];
37         $attributes['id'] = $attributes['entryId'];
38         $attributes['revisionNotes'] = $attributes['notes'];
39         $title = $entryData['title'];
40         unset($attributes['data'], $entryData['fields'], $attributes['entryId'], $attributes['notes'], $entryData['title']);
41 
42         $attributes = array_merge($attributes, $entryData);
43 
44         // Initialize the version
#2  
–  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/services/EntryRevisionsService.php(373): Craft\EntryVersionModel::populateModel(array("id" => "21738", "entryId" => "8090", "sectionId" => "5", "creatorId" => "260", ...))
368             $result['data'] = JsonHelper::decode($result['data']);
369 
370             // Don't initialize the content
371             unset($result['data']['fields']);
372 
373             $versions[] = EntryVersionModel::populateModel($result);
374         }
375 
376         return $versions;
377     }
378 
#3  
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/variables/EntryRevisionsVariable.php(86): Craft\EntryRevisionsService->getVersionsByEntryId("8090", "zh", 10)
#4  
 unknown(0): Craft\EntryRevisionsVariable->getVersionsByEntryId("8090", "zh")
#5  
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(688): call_user_func_array(array(Craft\EntryRevisionsVariable, "getVersionsByEntryId"), array("8090", "zh"))
#6  
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(64): Twig_Template->getAttribute(Craft\EntryRevisionsVariable, "getVersionsByEntryId", array("8090", "zh"), "method", ...)
#7  
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/d9/d9be2a6a0ed6d275eb077a791e70d5e4652cbcd3eb25e34da6578923225bfafe.php(104): Craft\BaseTemplate->getAttribute(Craft\EntryRevisionsVariable, "getVersionsByEntryId", array("8090", "zh"), "method")
#8  
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_36c428e0e064fa5cf2103ac0505dde32a4b866389b95b5b0643bd11134e0fca5->doDisplay(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array())
#9  
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(26): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array())
#10 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array())
#11 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/3d/3de5b5cd9108c8dcc80b8726941bb48f2ec5837fba9b56f724c0ebeeff7f2f6c.php(68): Twig_Template->display(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...))
#12 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(215): __TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb->block_pageTitle(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("head" => array(__TwigTemplate_c54f60077735addcf30be6f2be3e0d0ef68dfd293da2c31c649ad159a98ea7d1, "block_head"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), "foot" => array(__TwigTemplate_07f1ed1ad1b01b621d194464a3a48f3c95689b7413936dac9ab37f6eab989f4e, "block_foot"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), ...))
#13 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/02/02b83c11d5755246fe66a5d66d39b49cdeecf2ff0bb146e307380ce6b0b66f04.php(872): Twig_Template->displayBlock("pageTitle", array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("head" => array(__TwigTemplate_c54f60077735addcf30be6f2be3e0d0ef68dfd293da2c31c649ad159a98ea7d1, "block_head"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), "foot" => array(__TwigTemplate_07f1ed1ad1b01b621d194464a3a48f3c95689b7413936dac9ab37f6eab989f4e, "block_foot"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), ...))
#14 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(215): __TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065->block_pageHeader(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("head" => array(__TwigTemplate_c54f60077735addcf30be6f2be3e0d0ef68dfd293da2c31c649ad159a98ea7d1, "block_head"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), "foot" => array(__TwigTemplate_07f1ed1ad1b01b621d194464a3a48f3c95689b7413936dac9ab37f6eab989f4e, "block_foot"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), ...))
#15 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/02/02b83c11d5755246fe66a5d66d39b49cdeecf2ff0bb146e307380ce6b0b66f04.php(668): Twig_Template->displayBlock("pageHeader", array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("head" => array(__TwigTemplate_c54f60077735addcf30be6f2be3e0d0ef68dfd293da2c31c649ad159a98ea7d1, "block_head"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), "foot" => array(__TwigTemplate_07f1ed1ad1b01b621d194464a3a48f3c95689b7413936dac9ab37f6eab989f4e, "block_foot"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), ...))
#16 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(215): __TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065->block_body(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("head" => array(__TwigTemplate_c54f60077735addcf30be6f2be3e0d0ef68dfd293da2c31c649ad159a98ea7d1, "block_head"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), "foot" => array(__TwigTemplate_07f1ed1ad1b01b621d194464a3a48f3c95689b7413936dac9ab37f6eab989f4e, "block_foot"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), ...))
#17 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/e2/e214d71cd9be8c9f7e84e32ee4a027a2857d3baa0c663997875ef429ae28f48c.php(45): Twig_Template->displayBlock("body", array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("head" => array(__TwigTemplate_c54f60077735addcf30be6f2be3e0d0ef68dfd293da2c31c649ad159a98ea7d1, "block_head"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), "foot" => array(__TwigTemplate_07f1ed1ad1b01b621d194464a3a48f3c95689b7413936dac9ab37f6eab989f4e, "block_foot"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), ...))
#18 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_c54f60077735addcf30be6f2be3e0d0ef68dfd293da2c31c649ad159a98ea7d1->doDisplay(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("head" => array(__TwigTemplate_c54f60077735addcf30be6f2be3e0d0ef68dfd293da2c31c649ad159a98ea7d1, "block_head"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), "foot" => array(__TwigTemplate_07f1ed1ad1b01b621d194464a3a48f3c95689b7413936dac9ab37f6eab989f4e, "block_foot"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), ...))
#19 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(26): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("head" => array(__TwigTemplate_c54f60077735addcf30be6f2be3e0d0ef68dfd293da2c31c649ad159a98ea7d1, "block_head"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), "foot" => array(__TwigTemplate_07f1ed1ad1b01b621d194464a3a48f3c95689b7413936dac9ab37f6eab989f4e, "block_foot"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), ...))
#20 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("head" => array(__TwigTemplate_c54f60077735addcf30be6f2be3e0d0ef68dfd293da2c31c649ad159a98ea7d1, "block_head"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), "foot" => array(__TwigTemplate_07f1ed1ad1b01b621d194464a3a48f3c95689b7413936dac9ab37f6eab989f4e, "block_foot"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), ...))
#21 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/2f/2fd2b813b122bdc2d5da0e30d9cae2fe97d13e8c3e73a47e1cb132d0558ff3e7.php(131): Twig_Template->display(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("foot" => array(__TwigTemplate_07f1ed1ad1b01b621d194464a3a48f3c95689b7413936dac9ab37f6eab989f4e, "block_foot"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), "containerAttributes" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_containerAttributes"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), ...))
#22 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_07f1ed1ad1b01b621d194464a3a48f3c95689b7413936dac9ab37f6eab989f4e->doDisplay(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("foot" => array(__TwigTemplate_07f1ed1ad1b01b621d194464a3a48f3c95689b7413936dac9ab37f6eab989f4e, "block_foot"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), "containerAttributes" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_containerAttributes"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), ...))
#23 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(26): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("foot" => array(__TwigTemplate_07f1ed1ad1b01b621d194464a3a48f3c95689b7413936dac9ab37f6eab989f4e, "block_foot"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), "containerAttributes" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_containerAttributes"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), ...))
#24 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("foot" => array(__TwigTemplate_07f1ed1ad1b01b621d194464a3a48f3c95689b7413936dac9ab37f6eab989f4e, "block_foot"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), "containerAttributes" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_containerAttributes"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), ...))
#25 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/02/02b83c11d5755246fe66a5d66d39b49cdeecf2ff0bb146e307380ce6b0b66f04.php(169): Twig_Template->display(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), "containerAttributes" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_containerAttributes"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), "pageHeader" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_pageHeader"), ...))
#26 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065->doDisplay(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), "containerAttributes" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_containerAttributes"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), "pageHeader" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_pageHeader"), ...))
#27 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(26): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), "containerAttributes" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_containerAttributes"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), "pageHeader" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_pageHeader"), ...))
#28 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), "containerAttributes" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_containerAttributes"), "body" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_body"), "pageHeader" => array(__TwigTemplate_573c28a777a5dbdb7b6c97825293c782778f8ae77dca884c1018a5906d345065, "block_pageHeader"), ...))
#29 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/3d/3de5b5cd9108c8dcc80b8726941bb48f2ec5837fba9b56f724c0ebeeff7f2f6c.php(53): Twig_Template->display(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("pageTitle" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_pageTitle"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), "main" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_main")))
#30 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(432): __TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb->doDisplay(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("pageTitle" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_pageTitle"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), "main" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_main")))
#31 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(26): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("pageTitle" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_pageTitle"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), "main" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_main")))
#32 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(403): Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...), array("pageTitle" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_pageTitle"), "saveButton" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_saveButton"), "main" => array(__TwigTemplate_ddfe54aed58b8e0a698cbb4e30ad20c1917cb4cb5d89cb094b63bcadc80bd9eb, "block_main")))
#33 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(411): Twig_Template->display(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...))
#34 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(362): Twig_Template->render(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...))
#35 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php(256): Twig_Environment->render("entries/_edit", array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...))
#36 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/controllers/BaseController.php(74): Craft\TemplatesService->render("entries/_edit", array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...))
#37 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/controllers/EntriesController.php(342): Craft\BaseController->renderTemplate("entries/_edit", array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh", ...))
#38 
 unknown(0): Craft\EntriesController->actionEditEntry(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh"))
#39 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CAction.php(109): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Craft\EntriesController, array(array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh")))
#40 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(47): CAction->runWithParamsInternal(Craft\EntriesController, ReflectionMethod, array("p" => "admin/entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival...", "variables" => array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh"), "template" => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh"))
#41 
+  /Users/romain/Desktop/matsuri/matsuri/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(array("p" => "admin/entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival...", "variables" => array("matches" => array(0 => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh", "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", 1 => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", ...), "sectionHandle" => "reportsArticle", "entryId" => "8090", "localeId" => "zh"), "template" => "entries/reportsArticle/8090-shibukawa_bellybutton_festival/zh"))
```

Comment: You're getting that error from the Control Panel? Can you enable devMode and edit the original question to share the whole stack trace?

Comment: @BradBell Hi Brad, I edited the question. Does that help understanding the issue? Thanks

Comment: It does... adding an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your stack trace and description, it looks like some of the entry versions in the zh (Chinese) locale are missing their `title` field.  No idea how that happened (every entry and version should always have a title), but that's the cause of the error.

The particular entry that's causing the error you're getting has an ID of `8090`.

If the revisions aren't particularly important, you can delete them from the `craft_entryversions` table where `entryId` = 8090 for this example.

If they are, you can edit the JSON encoded `data` column in that table to include a `"title"` attribute.

Comment: Thanks!
I simply disabled the versioning for my section as I did not really need it. It solved it!